# How to Send an Email with Amazon SES using Serverless DynamoDB Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-nodejs

How to Send an Email with Amazon SES using NodeJS serverless DynamoDB
and i tried with the below code

can anyone say what iss proper solution

```
const params = {
    id: uuid.v1(),
    to: 'recipient@example.com',
    from: 'sender@example.com',
    subject: 'Test Email',
    message: '<p>Hello World!</p>'
};
const emailParams = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: \[params.to\]
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Html: {
                Data: params.message
            }
        },
        Subject: {
            Data: params.subject
        }
    },
    Source: params.from
};

ses.sendEmail(emailParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with dynamodb? And what is your problem with above code?

Comment: is that above code is  proper solution?

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Does it do what you want it to do? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: yeah its running now just a declaration issue